# Cut, rotate and interpolate raster heightmap with QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

I have some raster heightmap (example, GeoTIFF). I need to cut a rectangle at a specified angle, rotate this rectangle to a horizontal matrix and interpolate it.

I'll try to explain in more detail (using a combination of QGIS & GIMP).

1) Open map.

2) Create rectangle. 
I create a new vector layer with polygon type and insert 4 points with the mouse. Maybe I can insert a rectangle as it is easier and more accurate?

3) Clipper.
Menu: Raster -> Extraction -> Clipper.

4) I got a rectangular piece of map, but do not know what to do next.
[image]

**Next steps I will do in GIMP.** (because I don't know how to show it in QGIS)

5) Rotate the map horizontally.

6) Set grid with a given accuracy and consider the average value of the height, which fell in the grid cell.

[image]

7) Save new XY matrix to some file.

How can I do it only with QGIS? 
How can I do it with only GDAL and Proj4?

Comment: Couple questions:  What is the purpose of rotating the DEM? once rotated it has lost all value as the data won't match to anything.  QGIS does allow for map rotation, which is on the bottom bar beside the render box.  Why do you need to use GIMP?  A quick search and I don't think GIMP can handle geotiff or other spatial files, just images.  The second you turn the DEM to an image it has lost its data and your left with black-white pixels.  If you are just after an image would not setting up a simple print composer and rotating the map window and save as image suffice?

Comment: I used GIMP for example only. I want to get just an array of values XY with a given grid. I will use these data later in other algorithms which do not need a reference to the geographical data.

Comment: If I do it with standard tools I get a grid in a different projection. I want my upper-left cell of the grid lay on the upper-left corner of the map  and the bottom-right cell of the grid lay on the bottom right corner of the map.
[Image with stantard grid](https://habrastorage.org/files/f1e/2fc/539/f1e2fc539f2a4a4284a83958da038d5d.png)